¿Configuracion proxy pass para app de vite react?
Buenas espero me puedan guiar, tengo una app de react con vite en un servidor nginx.
Inicialmente accediamos mediante URL:puerto.
Queremos usar sólo la URL asi que pensamos en hacer un proxy pass, con el puerto 80 y el puerto 5173 de vite, pero al hacerlo nos da error 502.
El proyecto, lo subí al servidor por ftp, no sé si tendría que instalar algo más.
Dejo el codigo del sites-enabled y el de vite.conf.js
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name horariospers.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5173;  
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    root /home/abrizuela/front/proy-icunc/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location /static/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

vite:
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
}) 


lo q veo como posible origen del 502 es que pone localhost en vez de 127.0.0.1  y la variable de entorno que contiene el host por lo general es $http_host ( proxy_set_header Host $http_host; ) . el dominio cuenta con ceritficados para https ?

No, todavía no le pusimos los certificados, estamos probando en la red local por ahora.

1/ tene en cuenta que si la app es sólo client side onda spa con todo el asunto bundleado por vite en la carpeta dist, no haría falta un proxy. si contiene/incluye server side rendering o un api o por ejemplo un server.js ( tipicamente node.js ) ahi si levantas el server con por ejemplo pm2 y le haces el proxy pass

2/ el server.js ( o el api ) por lo general conviene bindearlo a / levanatrlo en una unica ip / interfaz local o interna, tipicamente 127.0.0.1. localhost no siempre es equivalente a la ip 127.0.01 de ahí que para simplificar usas la ip y definis la ip al levantar el server ( un efecto extra es que no queda expuesto al exterior de ahi que se ponga un proxy pass )

3/ si vite no esta corriendo ( sirviendo el bundled ) o en ciertos casos si el "localhost" que ve vite no es el mismo que ve nginx ( puede ser ::1 por ejemplo )  ahi falla el proxy ( 502 error interno )

Tenemos el back en el mismo servidor del front, y el vite con.la carpeta dist. Es la primera vez q intento configurar el nginx por eso no entiendo mucho de eso, disculpá. El asunto fue que no queremos q los usuarios ingresen x la URL:5173.. pensamos en escuchar x el puerto 80 y que de ahi se redirija al 5173, por eso estabamos intentando lo del proxypass. Pero vite no esta instalado en ese server, puede ser x eso el lio?
